# div:hover working only on last of type

Tags: jquery, css, hover

Got a really strange issue:

I have three elements using a simple exit button created in a div and controlled by jQuery, but I am using the :hover CSS selector to change opacity on hover.  Problem is that it is only working on the last of the three elements.  If I comment out the third, it works on the second, and so on. I've included a dumbed-down fiddle link here to show what I am working with. I can't find any solution or even reference to this problem anywhere and I have no idea what is causing it.

Demo: http://bit.ly/1rKVW7u

Try clicking each blue box and then hovering over the exit button in top right, and you'll see what I mean that the third blue box's pop-up window works and others do no.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you inspect the elements, the other buttons haven't inherited the :hover styling. I'm not sure why that is though.

Comment: Post a link to your fiddle without using yet another URL shortener and relevant code in your question as (afaik) asked when you tried to add a link to your fiddle without bit.ly

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit strange, but seems like no matter what window you choose, the `exit-btn` is always the third one.
Adding `display: none;` to the class `.work-type-window` solves this issue.
see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mLsr3csy/).

Answer (score 0):

You're using `position: fixed` for all your buttons, so they're at the exact same place except you only see the one that is opaque. The other are still in the way I guess (and IE11 may have a different behavior here).

Here the 3 exit links aren't one over the other anymore and each of them can be hovered with a style change: http://jsfiddle.net/f1xc6gwk/

Use `display: none`: there's a chance it'll also work better with screen readers (they don't read hidden content while they *may* read transparent content while sighted users won't read it: you might expect that all your users wouldn't be able to read transparent content)